# What is viewbox get used in SVG ?

Tags: svg

I was just going through **[THIS](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)** SVG article. I came across the following example explaining the viewbox:

```
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 20" >

    <rect x="20" y="10" width="10" height="5"
          style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;"/>

</svg>
```

The article explains the viewbox in the above example as follows;

> In this case the view box starts at 0,0 and is 50 wide and 20 high.
>   That means, that the 500 by 200 pixels  element internally uses a
>   coordinate system that goes from 0,0 to 50,20. In other words, every 1
>   unit in the coordinates used in the shapes inside the 
>   corresponds to 500/50 = 10 pixels in the width, and 200/20 = 10 pixels
>   in the height. That is why the rectangle with a x-position of 20 and
>   an y-position of 10 is really located at 200,100, and its width (10)
>   and height (5) corresponds to 100 pixels and 50 pixels.

Now my question is why is the viewbox needed when an SVG already has a width and height ? I am new to SVG and i don't see a compelling enough reason to use viewbox. can somebody explain why does viewbox get used ?

Comment: I've always used viewboxing to have dynamically sized SVGs - set the width and height to 100% and let the viewbox handle scaling.  Just an opinion though, not an answer.

Comment: @ScottKaye can u put in an answer an example of what your saying , because i still don't quite get it :)

Comment: Why don't you just display the SVG in the browser then remove the viewBox and display it again. See the difference?